# 3d geometry please help

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

A question from 3d geometry: Find the equation of the plane passing through the points $(1,2,3)$ and $(0,-1,3)$ and parallel to the line $R=i-2j+t(2i+3j-3k)$?

Comment: no i found this little difficult so i posted #zipirovich

Answer (score 1):

To find an equation of a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$, you need two things: a point in the plane and a vector normal to the plane. In this examples, you have the two given points to choose from, so the main goal here is to find a normal vector. Note that the given information allows you to find two vectors that lie **in the plane**: the directional vector of the given line (which you can see from the line's equation) and the vector connecting the two points in the plane. A normal vector would have to be perpendicular to both of them. Do you know which vector operation can take two vectors and create a result that's perpendicular to both of them?

Comment: thanks@zipirovich i got it